# Swift 1.2 - List type undeclared

Tags: xcode, swift, list, object

In my TableViewController i have this line of code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

In this block i try to get a list of objects

```
let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List
```

But i get this warning:

```
Use of undeclared type "List"
```

Anybody knows how to deal with it?

This is the full code:

```
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! list
    cell.textLabel?.text = list.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = list.url
    return cell
}
```

Any help is welcome!!

Greetings and Thanks

Comment: What's `List`? Where is that defined?

Comment: not sure, swa it in this core data tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6wceQnI2ko

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, Jason creates an entity called "**List**" in his Data Model file and then creates a class called **List**.

The following link starts the video just after he creates this file.
https://youtu.be/GeM7Zw12wbM?t=5m30s


You may have named your entity differently.

I named mine Record, since I'm storing records.
So my code will look like the following:

```
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        // ALL occurrences of "list" are instead "record"
        // ALL occurrences of "List" are instead "Record"

        let record = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Record
        cell.textLabel?.text = record.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = record.url

        return cell

}
```